# Laravel Sessions with jQuery work on PC browser, but not android?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, laravel

I have an a href, that when you click triggers jQuery to "GET" a web page, storing the item and quantity to my customers cart.

```
   $('a[href="#addToList"]').click(function () {
            //post to page to add to cart
            var itemID = this.attributes[1].value;
            $.getJSON("addToList.php?id=" + itemID, function () {
            })
                .success(function () {
                    Index.initCart();
                });

        });
```

Which will GET to this code:

```
      public function addToList()
{
    if(!isset($_GET['id']))
        return;

    SessionController::addToList($_GET['id'], 1);
}
```

Which all works on my PC, see for yourself. www.MyPCDeals.com Click "Add to list"  for one of the "New Arrivals", you will also see your cart change.

Session stuff:

```
       public static function addToList($itemID, $quantityOfItems = 1) {
    $cartArray = array();

    $sessionListItems = Session::get('listItem');
    if (isset($sessionListItems))
        $cartArray = Session::get('listItem');

    $itemToAddToCartArray = array(
    'id' => $itemID,
    'quantity' => $quantityOfItems
    );
    array_push($cartArray, $itemToAddToCartArray);


    session::put('listItem', $cartArray);
}
```

If you noticed, the success for the first a href code, refreshes cart, as well as first time page load by Index.initCart(); Here is the jQuery that updates the cart.

```
       public static function addToList($itemID, $quantityOfItems = 1) {
    $cartArray = array();

    $sessionListItems = Session::get('listItem');
    if (isset($sessionListItems))
        $cartArray = Session::get('listItem');

    $itemToAddToCartArray = array(
    'id' => $itemID,
    'quantity' => $quantityOfItems
    );
    array_push($cartArray, $itemToAddToCartArray);


    session::put('listItem', $cartArray);
}
```

Why does everything work on PC with no console errors, but does not work on my Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my web site had a strict MySQL mode, while my localhost PC did not.

This query fixed it: 
        SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';